# Как сделать Navigation Bar и Status Bar размытыми (UIBlurEffect) ? iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Господа, как сделать Navigation Bar и Status Bar размытыми (UIBlurEffect)? Когда я при нажатии на картинку скроллю вниз (Scroll View) к другим картинкам, эта картинка (в данном случае с белой машиной) просто теряется под Navigation Bar, а нужно что бы этот рисунок был виден под Navigation Bar с эффектом UIBlurEffect.
 [image: Не размытый Navigation Bar и Status Bar]

Я пробовал так, но не вышло:

```
func addBlurEffect() {
    // Add blur view
    let bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
    visualEffectView.frame = bounds!
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sendSubview(toBack: visualEffectView)
    visualEffectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Во первых, при скроллинге картинка так же пропадает под Navigation Bar.
Во вторых Status Bar остался серым.
[image: Status Bar не применил UIBlurEffect]

Для того что бы Status Bar НЕ оставался серым я попробовал сделать это, но безрезультатно =(

```
bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)
bounds.size.height = bounds.height + 20.0
```

Так же в AppDelegate (он в приложении написан на Objective-C) в didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, я пробовал добавить это, все осталось так же без изменений:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему, я вожусь с этим уже 2 суток.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код который помог мне, а особенно вторая строка:

```
let visualEffectView   = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
visualEffectView.frame =  (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -10).offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -10))!
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```